# Get database id from cursor to CustomAdapter (Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, custom-adapter

I know this might be dubbed as a duplicate question but i'm certain my case is quite unique. Basically i need a way to get my cursor id, that is the id from the database for my table parsed to the custom adapter. So that when i click on that list, it toast the correct id. Here is what i've got so far...

Please note that i want to use a customadapter and not a cursoradapter.

```
//Get Categories from database
    final Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getCategories(0);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                Categories categories = new Categories();
                categories.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                categories.set_categoryname(cursor.getString(2));
                categories.set_categoriescaption(cursor.getString(3));
                //list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbHandler.COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME)));
                categoriesList.add(categories);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Cursor get the data from my sqlite database

```
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.categories);

    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.cursor_row, categoriesList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String cid = String.valueOf(id);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), cid , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I want the real id of the table to be showed when i click the button and no the postion id. real id is supposed to b start from 1,, but i'm getting 0 here. Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much pondering on the internet, i found a solution that now makes lot of sense.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

The id from the onclick adapter view. I discovered that if it wasn't overridden, it will be set to the default position. So i passed my id in my customadapter and was able to see my id.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return data.get(position).Id;
}
```